# Trigger Before Insert MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a problem with my trigger before insert.
I try to control the row number of my table 'user_search' for one 'id_user' and if this row number > 4, the oldest row should be deleted.
My actual trigger is this :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_user_search 
BEFORE INSERT
ON user_search  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE sDate DATETIME;
    SELECT MIN(date_search) FROM user_search WHERE id_user = NEW.id_user INTO sDate;
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user_search WHERE id_user = NEW.id_user) > 4) THEN
        BEGIN
            DELETE FROM user_search WHERE date_search = sDate;
        END; 
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

However, it does not work. Do someone have a solution to help me please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not delete same table row during using INSERT trigger because it holds the **lock** of table. So try to write a Stored Procedure to insert new record.

**Stored Procedure** should be something like bellow:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_user_search(new_id_user INT, ......other variable to inert)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @minId INT;

  //INSERT using parameter

  SET @minId = SELECT MIN(id) FROM user_search WHERE id_user = new_id_user;
  IF ((SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user_search  WHERE id_user = new_id_user) > 4) THEN
        BEGIN
            DELETE FROM user_search WHERE id_user = @minId;
        END; 
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I tried your solution and it does not work.
If I remove the query restriction, the trigger won't have the correct behaviour. Before an insert, it will delete the oldest 'user_search's row without looking at the id_user concerned.
In my case, my application record all search make by the users and I do not want to get more 5 searches recorded for each user.

Comment: No, id_user is a foreign key linked on users(id)

Comment: It's a simple id auto incremented.
The table user_search is composed of 4 columns :
- id smallint Primary Key
- id_user smallint Foreign Key
- keyWords varchar
- date_search datetime